# creating unmanaged c++ project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unmanaged

Can not find the way how to create unmanaged visual C++ project in MS Visual Studio 2010. I select Visual C++ -> CLR -> Windows Form Applications. If it is already unmanaged, to get access to the textBox, i need to type textBox->Text, but this is the trait of managed, unmaged uses textBox.Text instead

Comment: You are very lost if you hope that you can use "textBox.Text" in an unmanaged app.  That's C# code, at best.  Any project you pick from the CLR node is a managed project and uses the C++/CLI language, not C++.  There is very little point in creating a Winforms app in C++/CLI, use C# instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no unmanaged Windows Forms project type. Windows Forms is part of the .NET Framework.

If you want an application for creating UIs in unmanaged C++, choose one of the MFC project types.